# Excel 2019 VSTO C# Replace is not working

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm encountering a strange issue with VSTO Excel 2019. 
For Excel 2016, it's working fine with below code:

```
Range.Replace("Old Value","New Value");
```

But if I run in Excel 2019. It doesn't update the cell value at all.

I think the problem is with Excel 2019 so I tried again using VBA Macro with below code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Replace What:="Old Value", Replacement:="New Value"
```

This time it is working fine in both Excel 2016 and 2019. I'm really not sure why **Replace** is not working with VSTO Excel 2019.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: rely on the Interop layer as little as possible. So what I would do if I were you is: read Range.Value into memory. Use robust C# libraries to do your replace. Write the value back out again.